# Show implicitly defined functions

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Is it possible to instruct GCC/Clang compiler to output the complete declaration/definition of a class with all the implicitly added functions?

If I define a class like

```cpp
class Test {
};
```

The compiler will modified this class and add *default constructor*, *assignment operator* etc. Is it possible to see these declarations/definition add by the compiler?

GCC provide `-E` option to output preprocessed source code. I'm trying to find a similar option to output the updated class declaration/definition.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that. What exactly do you need it for? Just for educational purposes? If so there is https://cppinsights.io/. Otherwise beware that explicitly declaring/defining the member functions does _not_ have the same effect as leaving them be implicitly declared with the exact same declaration/definition.

Comment: Yes, this is for educational purposes only. Just to verify the rule of three/five/zero.

Comment: I'm reading `EMC++S`. It mention the following for this structure declaration `struct S2 { S2(const S2&); };` 

"A user-provided copy constructor (1) suppresses the generation of the default
constructor and both move operations and (2) allows implicit generation of both the copy-assignment operator and the destructor. " How I can verify this?